# IronPython: no module named 'nltk'

Tags: python, c#, nltk, ironpython, bleu

i use ironPython last version 3.4.1 in Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython/3.4.1#readme-body-tab)

so, i got simple .py file with that code (let's name it test.py):

```
import nltk
def calculate_bleu(reference, candidate):
return nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu(reference, candidate)
```

and I have another .cs file which use IronPython package and executes this code (testME.cs) PS this is tests use NUnit 3.1:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
[TestCase]
public void TestIt()
    {

ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Users\my_user\repository\test.py");
            ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dir))
        {
            paths.Add(dir);
        }
        else
        {
            paths.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        }

        paths.Add(@"c:\Users\my_user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\nltk\translate\bleu_score.py");
        paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\Python311");
        paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib");
        paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\Python311\site-packages");
        paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\Python311\site-packages\nltk");

        engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
        engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\my_user\repository\test.py", scope);
        dynamic testFunction = scope.GetVariable("calculate_bleu");

        var result = testFunction("this is a dog", "this is a cat");
    }

}
```

so, when I run this code I got an error about 'NLTK' module like:
Message:

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException : No module named 'nltk'
>
> Stack Trace:  LightExceptions.ThrowException(LightException lightEx)
> LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow(Object value)
> FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
> Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
> LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
> PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx) PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope
> scope) RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
> RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope) SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope,
> ErrorSink errorSink) SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope)
> ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
> ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(String path, ScriptScope scope)

If i run this "@"C:\Users\my_user\repository\test.py"" thorugh console -> there is successfull result ( i tried execute 'print' -> it prints the result);
library nltk is installed globally for me;
I set up all python paths as SetSearchPaths (i googled it can be the solution)
nltk package version is 3.5 (i googled there are problems with less version of it)

are there any of the other possible solutions which could be helpful for me? i'd be happy for any info;
thank you

Comment: _library nltk is installed globally for me_ How do you know this?  What command did you run that showed you this information?

Comment: I can execute "pip show nltk" and see the version of the package (3.5) from any place (not only the repository folder with installed package)

Comment: Show us the output of `pip show nltk`, specifically the `Location:` line.  Also show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: there is the result of `import sys; print(sys.path)`: 
`['C:\\Users\\my_user\\repository', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311', 'C:\\Users\\my_user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']`

Comment: there is the result of `pip show nltk` (show the cmd look):
`C:\Users>pip show nltk
Name: nltk
Version: 3.5
Summary: Natural Language Toolkit
Home-page: http://nltk.org/
Author: Steven Bird
Author-email: stevenbird1@gmail.com
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages
Requires: click, joblib, regex, tqdm
Required-by: nltk-tgrep`

Comment: Did you execute `print(sys.path)` in exactly the same way  as the original code, i.e. using NUnit 3.1 with IronPython?

Comment: Also, I do see one difference -- that code output has `C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages`, but the `testME.cs` code you posted in the question has `C:\Program Files\Python311\site-packages`.  Those are quite different.

Comment: I installed package through Nuget and executed this import `sys; print(sys.path)` through the program run. there is a last result: 
[.
C:\Users\my_user\repository\bin\Debug\net6.0\lib
C:\Users\my_user\repository\bin\Debug\net6.0\DLLs
c:\Users\my_user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\nltk\translate\bleu_score.py
C:\Program Files\Python311
C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib
C:\Program Files\Python311\site-packages
C:\Program Files\Python311\site-packages\nltk
] ->>> I'll try to add "C:\Program Files\Python311\site-packages" too right now

Comment: I've set one more path like you said: `C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages` and it helped a little; now i've got "syntax error" with thread like:     `Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException : invalid syntax
Data:
  Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DynamicStackFrame: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DynamicStackFrame]
  IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.PythonExceptions+BaseException: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.PythonExceptions+ExceptionDataWrapper
  PreviousStackTraces: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Diagnostics.StackTrace]`

Comment: can it be connected to Python version etc?

Comment: I think so.  You've clearly got two separate installations of python, one in `C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311` and one in `C:\Program Files\Python311\site-packages`.  They're both Python 3.11, but it appears that `nltk` is installed for one of them but not the other.